# BeanIO : Multiple records in single row of file

Tags: java, fileparsing, bean-io

I have a text file with multiple lines(rows) that I am trying to read using BeanIO. The file looks like this:

> Adele|Lionel Richie|Hello|22865
>
> Ed Sheeran|Simple Plan|One|11230

Here, the line represents multiple artists that have a song with the same name.
Adele and Lionel Richie have a song called "Hello" and the song id is 22865. The number of columns is always 4 in each row

I need to parse this row to create 2 objects of Song

```
Class Song{
 String artistName;
 String songName;
 int songId;
}
```

First row above must give 2 Song objects :

> Adele , Hello and 22865
>
> Lionel Richie, Hello and 22865

Would this be possible using BeanIO? I have used the delimiter parsing ability of BeanIO to parse but not sure how to get multiple records for a single line

Comment: Since your records don't have a fixed format, i.e. a fixed number of columns, you can't use automatic object mapping libraries. You need to parse the lines yourself, which should be easy using `BufferedReader` and `split()`, assuming no value can contain a `|` character.

Comment: I looked into the data further, Looks like there are fixed 4 columns on all rows. I have edited the question to mention this

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidelines on the documentation:

http://beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#RecordGroups

```
Class Song{
 List<String> artistName;
 String songName;
 int songId;
}
```

This way you can have as many artists as you want

```
<record name="artistName" collection="list" >
...
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link! I need two different Song objects from each line in the file. Since eventually they will translate to two rows in a DB table.